# When does a new day start on Math.SE?

Tags: support

I've been wondering, I live in a GMT+1 area and have seen my total consecutive days visited been reset even when I did visit the site every day. Also noticed that rep from a new day (in my timezone) got added to the previous day. It got me to this question: when does a new day start? Is it subjective to a user's preferences? Meta seemed like a right place to ask.

Comment: Let me also add that for the purpose of "consecutive days visited", IIRC the front page doesn't count: you need to actually click through to read some content to register as having visited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Coordinated Universal Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC), if I am not mistaken.

Comment: It is currently 0:26 (GMT), so a new day has begun. Yet I just got an upvote on an answer and the rep was still added to December, 3. EDIT: never mind, it just took some time. Looks like you are correct, thank you.